# Gmap3 clear and add marker too fast causes delay

Tags: javascript, performance, jquery, google-maps-api-3, jquery-gmap3

I try to implement dynamic marker list come from server. I notice that when user click the button quite fast (0.5 sec/s for example), the markers re-appear with huge delay (sometimes over 3 secs)... ? What could causing that? Here's my code. Thanks so much ?

```
          $("a#userBookmark").click(function () {
              $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "Details.aspx/LoadUserBookmark",
                  data: "",
                  contentType: "application/json",
                  dataType: "json",
                  success: function (res) {
                      if (!res.d) {
                          window.location = "login.aspx?url=" + "<%= clsStringExtensions.base64Encode("Details.aspx")%>";
                      }
                      else {
                          $("#MapDetail").gmap3({
                              clear: {
                                  name: "marker",
                                  all: true
                              },
                              marker: {
                                  values: res.d,
                                  options: {
                                      draggable: false
                                  },
                                  events: {
                                      click: function (marker, event, context) {
                                          var map = $(this).gmap3("get"),
                                            infowindow = $(this).gmap3({ get: { name: "infowindow" } });
                                          if (infowindow) {
                                              infowindow.open(map, marker);
                                              infowindow.setContent(context.data);
                                          } else {
                                              $(this).gmap3({
                                                  infowindow: {
                                                      anchor: marker,
                                                      options: {
                                                          content: context.data,
                                                          maxWidth: 400
                                                      }
                                                  }
                                              });
                                          }
                                      }
                                      //                         mouseout: function () {
                                      //                             var infowindow = $(this).gmap3({ get: { name: "infowindow" } });
                                      //                             if (infowindow) {
                                      //                                 infowindow.close();
                                      //                             }
                                      //                         }
                                  }
                              }
                          });
                      }

                  },
                  error: function (errorObjString) {
                      var err = $.parseJSON(errorObjString.responseText);
                      alert(err.Message);
                  }

              });
          });
```

Comment: please help.... No one using gmap3 ??

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has something to do with your server side code in ajax. The checking the load time of your resources in your web inspector like firebug or chrome developer tools.